# I am trying to make a discord bot that will sometimes give a random response python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not that good at programming and can not get this to work
I am getting the error "'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'"
I don't know how to fix it but StackOverflow is making me type more stuff
I do have discord.py installed
I have look at lots of pages on this
I don't relly know what to put hear

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    i = random.randint(0,30)
    elif i == 4:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 3:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 2:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 1:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 6:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 7:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 8:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 9:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 10:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 11:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 12:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 14:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 15:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 16:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 17:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 18:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 19:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 20:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 21:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 22:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 24:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 25:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'msg')
    elif i == 26:
        await client.send_message('msg')

    await client.process_commands(message)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try using a list that stores all of the responses, then it's just a matter of `random.choice(responses)`. Giant `if`-`else` statements are a mess to deal with.

Comment: Your huge if-else can be simplified into: `i in [4,3,2,6.....]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `await message.channel.send` instead of `await client.send_message`